# Green function of a 2D exterior domain

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider solutions of the laplace equation
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-\Delta u=f, \ \ u|_{\partial D}=0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. If $D$ is bounded smooth, from the classical elliptic theory (see Girberg-Trudinger's book, chapter 2), $u$ is
$$u(x)=\int_{D}G(x,y)f(y)dy,$$
where $G(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln |x-y|-h(x,y)$. Note that $h(\cdot,y)$ is determined by
$$-\Delta_x h(x,y)=0,\ \ h(x,y)|_{x\in\partial D}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln |x-y|.$$

What I want to ask is, if $D$ is an exterior domain (such as $B^c_1(0)$), whether $u$ has the above Green function? If has, then how to determine $h$? Clearly $h$ is harmonic. A problem is the condition of $h$ at infinity, since the fundamental solution is $\ln |x|$ at infinity, rather than $\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}$ when $n\geq 3$.

I also notice that when $D$ is an exterior domain, then the assumption of $f$ need to be stronger. Such as if $f\in L^p$ for some $p>1$, then the integration does not make sense. So in this case whether $f$ need to have compact support?

Comment: (1) Yes: the complement of a disk, as well as the complement of any non-polar set, is a *Greenian domain*, that is, it allows for a Green function, which can be used to construct solutions of the Poisson problem. Various constructions of the Green function are possible, for example, one can approximate $D$ with bounded domains from the inside, or integrate the heat kernel with respect to time. (2) As long as the integral with respect to the Green function is absolutely convergent, it defines a solution of the Poisson problem.

Comment: All potential theory problems in unbounded domains in dimension 2 can be reduced to those in bounded domain by the transformation of the independent variable $z\mapsto 1/(z-a)$. which preserves harmonicity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you recommend me some relevant literature bout the Greenian domain? You say green function of unbounded domain D can be approximated by bounded domains from the inside. How to prove it?